# Unmarshal/Marshal json with int set to 0 does not seem to work

Tags: json, go

I am trying to parse a **json** object into a **struct**, but *integer* values set to 0 won't work.

```
q := []byte(`{"string":"this is a string", "integer": 0}`)

type Test struct {
    String string `json:"string,omitempty"`
    Integer int `json:"integer,omitempty"`
}    

var qq Test
if err := json.Unmarshal(q, &qq); err != nil {
   panic(err)
}

queryStr, err := json.Marshal(qq)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(queryStr))
// Output: {"string": "this is a string"}
```

if I set the integer to anything but 0, this works fine.

even if I Unmarshal the object and set the Integer field to 0, Marshalling it back removes the "integer" field.

Why? and how to get around this?

**EDIT**:

from what I gather from the comments, `omitempty` triggers when value is 0. So now the disappearance makes sense.

I'm parsing json, editing it and forwarding it to another service, so this is unfortunate, especially as field not present defaults to other values than 0, and I would prefer not having to feed in the defaults for the downstream API.

So is there a way to omit empty values but keep 0?

or change empty to something else?

Do I need to have 2 structs: one for input and one for output?

Comment: you have `omitempty`, and 0 is the empty value.

Comment: i need omitemtpy as I may not have the field altogether but I also need the value to be 0. so is there a way around this?

Comment: if the field is not present, in the program it's used in, it defaults to a value, which is not 0. So no field will default to say 10, but i need to be able to set 0. Is there way to set a default value for a struct field?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use a pointer for the fields, so that the zero value of the JSON type can be differentiated from the missing value.

```
type Test struct {
    String  *string `json:"string,omitempty"`
    Integer *int    `json:"integer,omitempty"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/yvYSHxubLy

Comment: that seems to be the solution... Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

"omitempty" tag makes sense only for marshaling from **struct** to **JSON**. It skips empty values so they won't be in **JSON**. It doesn't affect unmarshaling in any way. Use pointers if you want to detect whether the field is specified in **JSON** or not. If the field is not specified, the pointer value will be **nil**.

Answer (score 3):

as the docs says in https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field
>   becomes a member of the object unless
>
> - the field's tag is "-", or
> - the field is empty and its tag specifies the "omitempty" option. The **empty values are false, 0, any nil pointer or interface value, and any
>     array, slice, map, or string of length zero**. The object's default key
>     string is the struct field name but can be specified in the struct
>     field's tag value. The "json" key in the struct field's tag value is
>     the key name, followed by an optional comma and options.

so no, unless you implement your own marshaller for your struct

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [json.Number](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Number).
Like

```
type Test struct {
    String  string         `json:"string,omitempty"`
    Integer json.Number    `json:"integer,omitempty"`
}
```

Modifying the example of @Jimb: https://play.golang.org/p/UzKnhvGhC1n